# Javascript Loading Effect to URLs

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have found the [youtube loading effect](http://pastebin.com/VpAysesv) which I want to use in my wordpress theme. As this demo shows the effect triggering with button event. I want to add this to my wordpress theme by triggering URL event onclick.

So how to call this effect in our theme, when any URL on page is clicked?

Any pointers or suggestions to achieve this would be helpful. :)

Comment: damn, can i understand the reason for negative vote?

Comment: because your question as you've phrased it doesn't have anything to do with WordPress specifically. your own answer doesn't really answer the question you originally asked.

Comment: doesn't matter anymore, it is solved. sometimes stackexchange is horros when people jump on attacking with authority.

Comment: it's not an attack, it's an attempt to maintain the quality of answers available to the community. stackexchange is not a support forum, it's an archive of knowledge. downvoting is simply a mechanism to improve the signal to noise ratio, don't take it personally.

Answer (score 0):

I added the Javascript file with the following code.

So if anyone is looking for this solution should use the below code in functions. I don't know who was so jobless to vote this question down but I am trying to fix my mistake of posting question here on stackexchange by answering my own question.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'gen_progressbar');
function gen_progressbar() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/gen-progress.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
```